# In a Quick Tabs module what does this display do in a TAB TYPE view?

Tags: views, blocks

[image]

There are two options in my [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) settings:

1. display:Master
2. block:sid(depends on the view you have selected)

I want to know their individual effects on output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128948/what-is-the-purpose-of-master-display-in-views-module-of-drupal-7-why-is-it-not) regarding purpose of Master Display in Views. It contains the standard settings for a view that take a effect when you create a new display in the view. If you don't have specific settings differing from master display in your other displays you could (and maybe should) use it in the Quicktab.